# missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python, string

Buenas espero que se me pueda ayudar con esta situación que tengo en un código que estoy realizando para un trabajo en clase.

Me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error sucede cuando selecciono la opción 3 directamente o si
seleciono la opción automaticamente se brinca al numero 3 sin preguntar y de ahi aparece el mensaje de error que previamente mencione.

El código que estoy tratando de implementar es el siguiente.

se aceptan sugerencias para optimizar mas mi código y pueda funcionar de antemano gracias.

```
import re 


def menu():
    print("1. Suma")
    print("2. Potencia de un numero")
    print("3. Caracteres de un texto")
    print("4. Vocales y consonantes ")
    print("5. Par o inpar ")
    print("6. bubble sort ")
    print("7. Salir")
    op = input ("Escriba la opcion:")
    op = int(op)
    if op==1: suma()
    elif op==2: Potencia()
    elif op==3: Conteo()
    
    
    
    else: exit()
    
def suma():
    print("")
    print ("Hacer sumas.")
    num1 = input("Numero 1: ")
    num2 = input("Numero 2: ")
    num1 = float(num1)
    num2 = float(num2)
    print ("Resultado: ", num1+num2)
    print("")
    menu()

def Potencia():
    print("")
    print ("Hacer Potencias.")
    
    b = int(input("Digite o número da base: "))
    n = int(input("Digite o número da potência: "))

    i = 1

    while i != (n+1):
        print (b ** i)
        i = i + 1
        
menu()
    
def Conteo(string):
    
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
    return re.sub(pattern, '', string)
      

string = input("Ingrese los caracteres para su conteo ")
# define all digits as string
all_digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

# define all letters
all_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
            'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# given string

# initialized value
total_digits = 0
total_letters = 0

# iterate through all characters
for s in string:

    # if character found in all_digits then increment total_digits by one
    if s in all_digits:
        total_digits += 1

    # if character not found in all_digits then increment total_letters by one
    else:
        total_letters += 1

print("Total letters found :-", total_letters)
print("Total digits found :-", total_digits)



print(Conteo(string))
    
menu()
```

> Muchas gracias

Comment: La opción 3 llama a la función Conteo, que debería de recibir un argumento llamado string. No le estás pasando ese argumento. Se que es algo obvio lo que dije ya que es lo que dice el error, pero sin cierta información no puedo decir nada más. Que debería pasar cuando se elige la opción 3 o se llama a Conteo sin ese argumento?

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado.